# Requested document was not found when trying to upgrade Sitecore CD

Tags: upgrade, content-delivery

I am trying to upgrade my Sitecore installation from 8.1 original release to 8.2 original release.

I've successfully upgraded my CM instance, and so now I'm trying to do the same thing for my CD instance. I've downloaded the Upgrade Guide from [the Sitecore documentation site](https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore_Experience_Platform/82/Sitecore_Experience_Platform_82_Initial_Release.aspx), and I've gotten to step 1.2.3, where I upgrade the update installation wizard. It says to log into the CD instance and then run the Update Installation Wizard package.
[image: Instruction Snippet]

So as soon as I try to log into my CD instance, I get the following error:

[image]

At this point, I realize that of course I can't log into the CD instance of Sitecore, because I've disabled that functionality. My understanding is that is standard functionality to not allow CD instances to be logged into and have access to the desktop, as it could be a security risk if someone were to gain access to a login.

So, while I can temporarily allow access to the desktop for my test servers, I'm not sure that is such a good idea for running this on wizard on my **Production** CD server.

What is the proper way to upgrade my CD instance?

Comment: If you already successfully upgraded your CM environment, I would just install Vanilla Sitecore 8.2 for a CD, apply your custom code, apply hardening guide, and bam! CD server. I can make this an answer if it seems appropriate.

Comment: The problem is that I've already got 3 CD instance in Production, and I'm trying to figure out how to upgrade those machines, not create a set of new CD servers. This is my first Sitecore upgrade, so I might be approaching it incorrectly. The last step in the upgrade guide (in Step 1.3.7) says to "Repeat all the steps in the upgrade process for every Sitecore instance that you want to update". I thought that meant for the CD, Reporting, etc. instances, but maybe that means something else?

Comment: CD servers should be identical. Filesystem and all. So "upgrade" one, and you can copy the Filesystem to the others.  The issue you're having is that the hardening took away all files needed to do the upgrade. technically the upgrade is done. All that needs to be done is copy over the file system from the CM server, to the CD server, reapply the hardening guide, then copy that server to the other CD's.  It's all about files on CD.

Comment: Obviosuly configuration files for CD also need to be done.

Comment: There's also a reasonable assumption that you already have a deployment process that sets the config files appropriately. that will need to be updated for 8.2, but should be minimal.

Comment: Thank you, Pete! I'm working on creating a deployment process that sets the config files appropriately for each environment. When we deployed our 8.1 environment, it was a manual process (OUCH!), and so I'm trying to get an automated process in place.

Comment: Awesome! Nice trick I learned from here was actually setting the hidden file attribute on a config to disable it. There are some cool Powershell scripts too. Just be aware the Excel Enable Disable.Config file has a few "bugs" in it.

Comment: Thanks! I found some of those "bugs" in the Enable Disable.config spreadsheet.

Comment: I don't recall seeing up there, but you may consider setting up a CM/CD on your desktop to troubleshoot the upgrade.

Comment: @MichaelWest I am doing that right now. That was how I found the issue.

Comment: @PeteNavarra After sleeping on your suggestion of just creating new instances of my other instances (i.e. CD, Processing and Aggregation, and Reporting), I think that your suggestion makes a lot of sense. I'm going to head down that path and see what other problems come my way. If you want to post that as an answer, I'd love to accept that. Thank you!